# How to insulate and air seal partially finished wall

Tags: walls, insulation, energy-efficiency, air-sealing

I'm trying to slowly improve the energy efficiency of my house. I need to finish a 2x6 framed wall between my basement mechanical room and a poorly insulated, unheated garage (There is living space above the garage). R21 fiberglass insulation was already installed in the wall with kraft paper stapled to the outside of the studs, overlapping, on the conditioned side. I had wanted to add an additional 6mil plastic air barrier over the insulation and under the drywall on the conditioned side.

But due to poor communication it was drywalled over without the air barrier, and now there's HVAC equipment installed on and near the wall making it extremely hard to remove the drywall. The garage side of the wall is still unfinished. I plan to seal all gaps with spray foam and caulk. Question: would it be a mistake to put the air barrier on the outside of the insulation, under the non-conditioned side drywall? I've read enough to know that generally this is a bad idea due to trapping moisture and condensation in the insulation. But:

- Colorado is fairly dry
- I have an ERV which will move air and help balance humidity
- There's now a heat pump water heater in the
  mechanical room (running in heat pump only mode) which vents to the
  garage. So, it will be drawing fresh air into the mechanical room
  fairly regularly.

Any thoughts and advice on the best (and safest) way to finish insulating and air sealing this wall now that I'm halfway down what's probably the wrong path, would be much appreciated. Thanks!